# iOS app is translated automatically when installed on iPad with other base language

Tags: ios, localization

We have a iOS app with no localization used. It's only men t to work in dutch.
One customer has an iPad with French as the main language set.
For some reason, the app (made with cordova) is translated automatically.
We checked and there is no language set for the specific app.
When the main language is changed to dutch then the app works as expected, but that's not what the customer wants.

What am I missing here

Answer (score 0):

System strings are automatically translated to the users preferred language (your own strings are obviously not) unless you set the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in the `Info.plist`.

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>nl-nl</string>
```

You should also consider setting `CFBundleLocalizations` to indicate which localisations you support.

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>nl-nl</string>
</array>
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundledevelopmentregion